# Watin C# NUnit IE COM Exception

Tags: internet-explorer, nunit, watin

I use Watin and Nunit for testing, All works fine on Windows 7.
But now I need to share my test on a server Windows 2008.
And It's a problem because I always get an exception when I try to Logout and then launch a new IE:
`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800704A6): Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800704a6.
   at WatiN.Core.IE.CreateNewIEAndGoToUri(Uri uri, IDialogHandler logonDialogHandler, Boolean createInNewProcess)`

I try to update IE to IE 9, same problem
I try to add some `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000)`, same problem.
I get this exception on this line:

```
return new IE(Config.DefaultConfig.HomepageUrl);
```

Thanks for your help,

Jerome

Answer (score 3):

I believe I had the same problem a while ago, but can't remember the exact solution so here is a couple of thinks you can try:

1. Did you add a reference to *Interop.SHDocVw* and *Microsoft.mshtml*?
2. And in their properties have you set **Embed Interop Types** to **False**?

Hope it helps. If some solution pops into my head I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to don't have anymore this message:

```
return new IE(Config.DefaultConfig.HomepageUrl, true);
```

To launch in a new process
And I add some

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
```

When Watin need to AttachBrowser.

But the problem is that now I get some COMException:

```
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (HRESULT: 0x80010108 RPC E DISCONNECTED)
```

this last message appear when I close a IE popup window. It don't find my mainpage after I close this popup window.

Thanks for your help,

Jerome

Comment: I think that's not a good way because with a new process, my tests doesn't work anymore on my Windows 7.